# KUBERNETES PODS:unable to mount nfs volume

Tags: kubernetes

I have some trouble mounting an nfs volume inside a docker container.
I have one minion(labcr3) and one pod(httpd-php).
Below you can find all relevant details.
Can you help me ?

Thanks and Regards

Phisical host(minion) is able to mount the nfs volume.

```
[root@LABCR3 ~]# df -h /NFS
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
192.168.240.1:/mnt/VOL1/nfs-ds 500G 0 500G 0% /NFS
```

Here the priviliged mode enable on kubernetes on minion 
    root@LABCR3 ~]# cat /etc/kubernetes/config | grep PRIV
    KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV="--allow_privileged=true"

Describe of pod

```
[root@labcr1 pods]# kubectl describe pod httpd-php 
Name: httpd-php
Namespace: default
Image(s): centos7-httpd-php-alive-new
Node: labcr3/10.99.1.203
Labels: cont=httpd-php-mxs,name=httpd-php
Status: Pending
Reason:

Message:

IP:

Replication Controllers: 
Containers:
httpd-php-mxs:
Image: centos7-httpd-php-alive-new
State: Waiting
Reason: Image: centos7-httpd-php-alive-new is ready, container is creating
Ready: False
Restart Count: 0
Conditions:
Type Status
Ready False 
Events:
FirstSeen LastSeen CountFrom SubobjectPath Reason Message
Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:29:48 +0100 Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:29:48 +0100 1 {scheduler } scheduled Successfully assigned httpd-php to labcr3
Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:31:53 +0100 Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:38:09 +0100 4 {kubelet labcr3} failedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "httpd-php_default": exit status 32
Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:31:53 +0100 Fri, 04 Dec 2015 15:38:09 +0100 4 {kubelet labcr3} failedSync Error syncing pod, skipping: exit status 32

Kubelet logs on minons

-- Logs begin at ven 2015-12-04 14:25:39 CET, end at ven 2015-12-04 15:34:39 CET. --
dic 04 15:33:58 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:33:58.986220 1423 pod_workers.go:111] Error syncing pod 7915461d-9a93-11e5-b8eb-d4bed9b48f94, skipping:
dic 04 15:33:58 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:33:58.973581 1423 kubelet.go:1190] Unable to mount volumes for pod "httpd-php_default": exit status 32;
dic 04 15:33:58 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
dic 04 15:33:58 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: Mounting arguments: labsn1:/mnt/VOL1/nfs-ds /var/lib/kubelet/pods/7915461d-9a93-11e5-b8eb-d4bed9b48f94/volumes/kube
dic 04 15:33:58 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:33:58.973484 1423 mount_linux.go:103] Mount failed: exit status 32
dic 04 15:31:53 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:31:53.939521 1423 pod_workers.go:111] Error syncing pod 7915461d-9a93-11e5-b8eb-d4bed9b48f94, skipping:
dic 04 15:31:53 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:31:53.927865 1423 kubelet.go:1190] Unable to mount volumes for pod "httpd-php_default": exit status 32;
dic 04 15:31:53 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
dic 04 15:31:53 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: Mounting arguments: labsn1:/mnt/VOL1/nfs-ds /var/lib/kubelet/pods/7915461d-9a93-11e5-b8eb-d4bed9b48f94/volumes/kube
dic 04 15:31:53 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:31:53.927760 1423 mount_linux.go:103] Mount failed: exit status 32
dic 04 15:21:31 LABCR3 kubelet[1423]: E1204 15:21:31.119117 1423 reflector.go:183] watch of *api.Service ended with: 401: The event in requested in
```

UPDATE 12/18/2015

Yes, is the first pod with nfs mount. 
nfs is mounted on the minion, so is working fine and there isn't ACL applyed to the nfs

this morning I've changed the config like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: httpd-php
  labels:
     name: httpd-php
     cont: httpd-php-mxs
spec:  
  containers:
  - name: httpd-php-mxs
    image: "centos7-httpd-php-alive-new"
    command: ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-DFOREGROUND"] 
    imagePullPolicy: "Never"
    ports:
     - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/NFS/MAXISPORT/DOCROOT"
      name: mynfs
  volumes:
  - name: mynfs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: nfs-claim

[root@labcr1 KUBE]# cat pv/nfspv.yaml 
  kind: PersistentVolume
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: nfspv
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 500Gi
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
    nfs:
      path: /mnt/VOL1/nfs-ds
      server: 10.99.1.202

[root@labcr1 KUBE]# cat pv/nfspvc.yaml 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
     - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi

[root@labcr1 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
httpd-php   1/1       Running   1          29m
[root@labcr1 ~]# kubectl get pv
NAME      LABELS    CAPACITY       ACCESSMODES   STATUS    CLAIM                   REASON
nfspv     <none>    536870912000   RWX           Bound          default/nfs-claim   


[root@labcr1 ~]# kubectl get pvc
NAME        LABELS    STATUS    VOLUME
nfs-claim   map[]     Bound     nfspv


[root@labcr1 ~]# kubectl describe pod httpd-php 
Name:               httpd-php
Namespace:          default
Image(s):           centos7-httpd-php-alive-new
Node:               labcr3/10.99.1.203
Labels:             cont=httpd-php-mxs,name=httpd-php
Status:             Running
Reason:             
Message:            
IP:             172.17.76.2
Replication Controllers:    <none>
Containers:
  httpd-php-mxs:
     Image:     centos7-httpd-php-alive-new
     State:     Running
       Started:     Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:39 +0100
     Ready:     True
     Restart Count: 1
 Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Ready     True 
 Events:
   FirstSeen                LastSeen            Count   From          SubobjectPath             Reason      Message
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100 1     {kubelet labcr3}  implicitly required container POD   pulled      Pod    container image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" already present on  machine
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100 1   {scheduler }                            scheduled   Successfully assigned httpd-php to labcr3
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    implicitly required container POD   created     Created with docker id 3b6d520e66b0
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:20 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    implicitly required container POD   started     Started with docker id 3b6d520e66b0
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:21 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:21 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    spec.containers{httpd-php-mxs}      started     Started with docker id 859ea73a6cdd
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:21 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 14:44:21 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    spec.containers{httpd-php-mxs}      created     Created with docker id 859ea73a6cdd
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    implicitly required container POD   pulled      Pod container image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" already present on machine
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    implicitly required container POD   created     Created with docker id bdfed6fd4c97
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:38 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    implicitly required container POD   started     Started with docker id bdfed6fd4c97
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:39 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:39 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    spec.containers{httpd-php-mxs}      created     Created with docker id ab3a39784b4e
   Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:39 +0100  Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:12:39 +0100 1   {kubelet labcr3}    spec.containers{httpd-php-mxs}      started     Started with docker id ab3a39784b4e
```

Now the minion is up and running but inside the pods I can't see the nfs mounted....

```
 [root@httpd-php /]# df -h
 Filesystem                                                                                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-253:2-3413-  f90c89a604c59b6aacbf95af649ef48eb4df829fdfa4b51eee4bfe75a6a156c3   99G     444M   93G   1% /
 tmpfs                                                                                               5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
 shm                                                                                                  64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                                             5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                                                           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /run/secrets
/dev/mapper/centos_labcr2-var                                                                   248G  3.8G  244G   2% /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Is this your first pod that tries to use NFS, or have you successfully mounted NFS before?  Can you ssh to a node and manually mount an NFS share with the same arguments?

Comment: @EricTune: Thanks for your reply: I've edited the question adding some news Thanks Mike

Comment: Error 32 usually indicates a nfs/rpc error. Are you able to mount your nfs share manually, using just "mount -t nfs 10.99.1.202:/mnt/VOL1/nfs-ds /some/local/path", on your minion that the trouble Pod was running on?